# Explicit Intent , Setpackage for Alarm or reminder

Tags: android, android-intent

I am trying to open mobiles Built-in alarm or reminder from my application by using
Explicit Intent, but I don't know what is the package name of reminder or alarm ..

```
intent.setPackage("com.packageName");
```

what will be the package name , please help me out sir ..

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
Intent i = new Intent(AlarmClock.ACTION_SET_ALARM); 
startActivity(i);
```

Comment: Please share logcat

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

`intent.setPackage(context.getApplicationContext().getPackageName())`

This will resolve (during runtime) to your package name regardless of what it actually is.